OpenMPI over Infiniband Pkey
I'm trying to use use openmpi over InfiniBand Pkey networks.
I can't seem to find any documentation on how to do that.
I'm using openmpi 4.1.2 and just a simple ring_c.
mpiexec -n 8 -host cn0001-pkey,cn0002-pkey /home/ring_c/ring_c

Networks:
cn0001
ib1 (default pkey) 10.1.0.101
ib1.00a0 (pkey 0xa0) 10.2.0.101

cn0002
ib1 (default pkey) 10.1.0.102
ib1.00a0 (pkey 0xa0) 10.2.0.102

I have my /etc/hosts file set so that
10.2.0.101  cn0001-pkey
10.2.0.102  cn0002-pkey

This seems to execute on cn0001, but hangs on cn0002. I don't think it's actually going over the pkey network.  What am I doing wrong?
mpiexec -n 8 -host cn0001-pkey,cn0002-pkey -mca plm_base_verbose 99 /home/ring_c/ring_c
[cn0001:05516] mca: base: components_register: registering framework plm components
[cn0001:05516] mca: base: components_register: found loaded component isolated
[cn0001:05516] mca: base: components_register: component isolated has no register or open function
[cn0001:05516] mca: base: components_register: found loaded component rsh
[cn0001:05516] mca: base: components_register: component rsh register function successful
[cn0001:05516] mca: base: components_register: found loaded component slurm
[cn0001:05516] mca: base: components_register: component slurm register function successful
[cn0001:05516] mca: base: components_open: opening plm components
[cn0001:05516] mca: base: components_open: found loaded component isolated
[cn0001:05516] mca: base: components_open: component isolated open function successful
[cn0001:05516] mca: base: components_open: found loaded component rsh
[cn0001:05516] mca: base: components_open: component rsh open function successful
[cn0001:05516] mca: base: components_open: found loaded component slurm
[cn0001:05516] mca: base: components_open: component slurm open function successful
[cn0001:05516] mca:base:select: Auto-selecting plm components
[cn0001:05516] mca:base:select:(  plm) Querying component [isolated]
[cn0001:05516] mca:base:select:(  plm) Query of component [isolated] set priority to 0
[cn0001:05516] mca:base:select:(  plm) Querying component [rsh]
[cn0001:05516] mca:base:select:(  plm) Query of component [rsh] set priority to 10
[cn0001:05516] mca:base:select:(  plm) Querying component [slurm]
[cn0001:05516] mca:base:select:(  plm) Selected component [rsh]
[cn0001:05516] mca: base: close: component isolated closed
[cn0001:05516] mca: base: close: unloading component isolated
[cn0001:05516] mca: base: close: component slurm closed
[cn0001:05516] mca: base: close: unloading component slurm
[cn0001:05516] [[33746,0],0] plm:rsh: final template argv:
        /usr/bin/ssh <template> ( test ! -r ./.profile || . ./.profile;           PATH=/opt/modules/openmpi/gcc/4.1.2/bin:$PATH ; export PATH ; LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/modules/openmpi/gcc/4.1.2/lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:-} ; export LD_LIBRARY_PATH ; DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/modules/openmpi/gcc/4.1.2/lib:${DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:-} ; export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH ;   /opt/modules/openmpi/gcc/4.1.2/bin/orted -mca ess "env" -mca ess_base_jobid "2211577856" -mca ess_base_vpid "<template>" -mca ess_base_num_procs "2" -mca orte_node_regex "cn[4:1],cn[4:2]-pkey@0(2)" -mca orte_hnp_uri "2211577856.0;tcp://16.1.15.2,10.1.0.201,10.2.0.101:38393" -mca plm_base_verbose "99" -mca plm "rsh" --tree-spawn -mca routed "radix" -mca orte_parent_uri "2211577856.0;tcp://16.1.15.2,10.1.0.201,10.2.0.101:38393" -mca pmix "^s1,s2,cray,isolated" )
[cn0002:05935] mca: base: components_register: registering framework plm components
[cn0002:05935] mca: base: components_register: found loaded component rsh
[cn0002:05935] mca: base: components_register: component rsh register function successful
[cn0002:05935] mca: base: components_open: opening plm components
[cn0002:05935] mca: base: components_open: found loaded component rsh
[cn0002:05935] mca: base: components_open: component rsh open function successful
[cn0002:05935] mca:base:select: Auto-selecting plm components
[cn0002:05935] mca:base:select:(  plm) Querying component [rsh]
[cn0002:05935] mca:base:select:(  plm) Query of component [rsh] set priority to 10
[cn0002:05935] mca:base:select:(  plm) Selected component [rsh]


After a but more experimenting, it appears openmpi is communicating to cn0002 over the correct pkey network, but is reaching back to cn0001 over the default pkey network, which it can't communicate over.
I know this because I set the default pkey network to full membership and suddenly the openmpi ring_c worked.
I've tried to tell it to only use that network by using --mca btl_tcp_if_exclude and --mca btl_tcp_if_include, but it doesn’t work.
There must be some way to restrict which network openmpi is using, but I can't find it.

I think I got this figured out. It worked over the default pkey because the MTU was set lower in the subnet manager than it was for pkeyA. For some reason it works with MTU=2048 on that IB partition, but not MTU=4096. I guess that’s a problem for another day.
